# How to get current location coordinates outside

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Firstly, I am very new at react native, therefore probably the question is basic. I am trying to get coordinates outside the getCurrentPosition function. I can get the console log of the details with below line:

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
```

The output is like that:

```
{"coords": {"accuracy": 20, "altitude": 0, "heading": 0, "latitude": 36.854074999999995, "longitude": 30.593996666666666, "speed": 0}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1642440006000}
```

But I couldn't find a way to take them outside. I want to use the result of this inside my functional component:

```
const Home = (props) => {
   return (
   <Text>Latitude is {latitude}</Text>
   <Text>Longitude is {longitude}</Text>
   )
}
export default Home
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useState() hook to achieve this.
https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting the value to a state assuming you are using react hooks

```
const [location,setLocation] = React.useState(); 

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => setLocation(info));
```

then

```
console.log(location.coords.latitude) //gives latitude
console.log(location.coords.longitude) //gives longitude
```

Comment: I am getting that error ----->    ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

Comment: did you set the value "setLocation(info)"

Comment: the error occurs if the value of location is undefined

Comment: no it is not undefined actually, it gives the output as in the post. I copied your answer, added -->   import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react"    But when I run, this error comes, I mean it doesn't see the coords of location parameter

Comment: if location has a value, and location.coords should be defined.

Comment: can i see the log of 'location'

Comment: ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in Home (at HomeScreen/index.js:12)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at HomeScreen/index.js:11)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at HomeScreen/index.js:10)
    in HomeScreen (at SceneView.tsx:126)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:118)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:210)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
......)

    in MyApp(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60), js engine: hermes

Comment: i ment the value of "console.log(location);" with out .coords

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241147/discussion-between-nhatty-and-anthon-santhez).